# what is the review procedure for Android Market?

Tags: android

Can someone give info on the review procedure followed by Google to publish an App in Android Market.

Comment: This reminds me of one of my favorite Stack Overflow questions ever. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233755/no-review-on-android-market-closed It was right to close it, but it still made me very happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none, until someone reports your App (malicious, copyright infringement etc)

Answer (score 2):

The Android app market (for better or worse) is completely regulated by the community... make whatever you want, but don't be surprised if someone reports your app for copyright infringement, inappropriate content, or what have you.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing an app is instant, and very easy. Just go into the Android market developer panel, click "Upload application", and then upload its file and type the desired information. Once you submit it, it appears in the Market instantly.

It is only taken down later if users report it as being a bad app.